# Array passed as parameter not accessible outside of user defined function

Tags: arrays, c, function, char, printf

This code is to convert a inputted decimal number to binary, hex, and octal without format specifiers. It also is supposed to print the results to a text file. Every works fine except the 3 char arrays storing hex, oct, and binary are not accessible outside of the function that converted them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

char *getDateAndTime();

int getInteger();

int atoi(const char *str);

void decimalToBinary(int decValue, char binString[]);

void decimalToHex(int decValue, char hexString[]);

void decimalToOct(int decValue, char octString[]);

int saveFile(char name[], char *getDateAndTime(), int decValue, char octString[], char  hexString[], char binString[]); 

int main()
{
    char binString[32];
    char octString[32];
    char hexString[32];
    char dateTime[32];
    char name[32];
    int decValue = 0;
    int saveSuccess = 0;
    
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
    decValue = getInteger();
    if (decValue != 'x'){
        decimalToHex(decValue, hexString);
        decimalToOct(decValue, octString);
        decimalToBinary(decValue, binString);
        saveFile(name, getDateAndTime, decValue, octString, hexString,  binString); 
        
    }
    printf("\nGoodbye!");
    return 0;
}

char *getDateAndTime()
{
    time_t t;
    time(&t);
    return ctime(&t);
}

int getInteger()
{
    char number[9];
    int num;
    int status = 1;
    do {
        printf("Enter an Integer [1-1,000,000] or type x to exit: ");
        fgets(number, sizeof(number), stdin);
        if (number[0] == 'x')
        {
            status = 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            num = atoi(number);
            if (num < 1 || num > 1000000)
            {
                printf("Error: %d is out of range\n", num);
            }
            else
            {
                status = 0;
                return num;
            }
        }
        
    } while (status);

}

void decimalToBinary(int decValue, char binString[])
{
    int quotient;
    int i = 1;
    int j;
    quotient = decValue;
    while(quotient!=0){
        binString[i++]= quotient % 2;
        quotient = quotient / 2;
    }
    printf("Decimal: %d\nBinary: ",decValue);
    for(j = i -1 ;j> 0;j--)
    printf("%d",binString[j]);
    printf("\n");
}

void decimalToHex(int decValue, char hexString[]){
    long int remainder,quotient;
    int i=1,j,temp;
    quotient = decValue;
    while(quotient!=0){
        temp = quotient % 16;
        if( temp < 10)
        temp =temp + 48;
        else
        temp = temp + 55;
        hexString[i++]= temp;
        quotient = quotient / 16;
        
    }
    printf("Hexadeciaml: ");
    for(j = i -1 ; j> 0; j--)
    printf("%c",hexString[j]);
}

void decimalToOct(int decValue, char octString[])
{
    int quotient;
    int i = 1;
    int j;
    quotient = decValue;
    while(quotient!=0){
        octString[i++]= quotient % 8;
        quotient = quotient / 8;
    }
    printf("\nOctal: ");
    for(j = i -1 ;j> 0;j--)
    printf("%d",octString[j]);
    printf("\n");
}

int saveFile(char name[], char* getDateAndTime(), int decValue, char octString[], char hexString[], char binString[])
{
    char choice;
    int status = 1;
    printf("Save to a file? (y/n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &choice);
    while (status){
        if (choice == 'y'){
            
            FILE *ptr_file;
            ptr_file =fopen("G01303907_HW3.txt", "w");
            if (!ptr_file){
                return 1;
            }
            int results = fprintf(ptr_file,"Name: %s\nDate: %s\nDecimal Value:%d\nHexadecimal String: %s\nOctal String: %s\nBinary String: %s\n",name, getDateAndTime(), decValue, hexString, octString, binString);
        
            if (results == EOF) {
                printf("Error: ");
            }
            fclose(ptr_file);
            
            status = 0;
            return 0;
        }
        else if (choice == 'n')
        {
            status = 0;
            return -1;
        }
        else{
            printf("Error: illegal value\nSave to a file? (y/n): ");
            scanf("%s", &choice);
        }
    } 
}
```

terminal

```
Enter an Integer [1-1,000,000] or type x to exit: 23
Hexadeciaml: 17
Octal: 27
Decimal: 23
Binary: 10111
Save to a file? (y/n): y

Goodbye!
```

Text Document

```
Name: Mason
Date: Mon Oct  3 23:38:59 2022

Decimal Value:23
Hexadecimal String: 
Octal String: 
Binary String:
```

Comment: In `void decimalToOct(int decValue)`, where do you think the definition of `octString` comes from ? Do the other two functions argument lists not suggest there may be something wrong with that function?

Comment: You also don't null terminate your strings. You leave the first character of your strings as garbage. (arrays in C start from 0, not 1). And for binary and octal you don't convert from digit value to character encoding. Your title question, OTOH isn't an issue.

Comment: Sorry, void decimalToOct(int decValue, char octString[]) is what I have. The problem is that the arrays I'm passing as a parameter to the 3 void functions are not accessible outside of the function. This is why the saveFile function simply prints them as blank arrays because the local array in the main function was never altered.

Comment: You can't type `x` to exit with that code. If you type `x`, `atoi(number)` will return `0`, not `'x'`.

Comment: That isn't real code. `void decimalToOct(int decValue, char octString)` clearly isn't correct. The latter argument should be `char octString[]`. And I honestly have no idea what your intentions of `char* getDateAndTime()` as an argument to `saveFile` is all about either. Regardless, the code as-presented cannot compile, much less run. Do *not* "fix" code in the editor here on a prayer; *test* it first, and make *sure* what you post exhibits the exact symptoms of the precise problem you're trying to fix. Otherwise, it just wastes your time, and ours.There are a LOT of errors in the posted code.

Comment: Another problem: You're missing the second argument when you call `decimalToOct()`

Comment: Notice that when you print the hex, octal, and binary strings in those functions you print the characters in reverse. You'll need to do the same thing when writing them to the file. But the functions know the last array index of the numbers, `saveFile` doesn't know the last index.

Comment: Ok all those errors were due to me trying different things but none of them are a catastrophic problem. The code does indeed compile and run and it does indeed exit when 'x' is entered. Everything is updated and correct and the only problem now is the char array parameters not being passed correctly and only existing within the user defined functions.

Comment: [Tried it. Not so](https://godbolt.org/z/sfrbsszYf).

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/49xVEtOYw

Comment: Your real error is that you start indexing with 1, but in C the first element of an array has the index 0. -- However, you need to correct all other errors, to.. Please raise the warning level of your compiler to the maximum and correct your code.